# Firebase Cloud messaging doesn't work for Build variant on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have 2 projects in Firebase: **nl.companyname** and **nl.companyname.acc**:

[image]

This is my build.gradle:

```
flavorDimensions "type"
productFlavors {
    acceptance {
        dimension="type"
        applicationIdSuffix ".acc"
        versionNameSuffix "-acc"
    }
    production {
        dimension="type"
        applicationIdSuffix ""
        versionNameSuffix ""
    }
}
```

The download google-services.json is in directory:
**app/google-services.json**

Android Studio is logged in to the Google account and synchronized:

[image]

The message shows up as successfully sent:
[image]

Problem description:

- When sending a message on **nl.companyname**, it works.
- When sending a message and targeting the device's **Token ID**, it works.
- But the **nl.companyname.acc** doesn't work.

Steps tried:

- I've deleted the .acc App in Firebase and re-added it (and downloaded the new json file).

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to change the approach to adding google-services.json  file in app folder.there is alternative solutions which you need to use.

Answer (score 8):

In the [Firebase Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/#support_multiple_environments_in_your_android_application), it supports multiple flavor based project.

> You can have multiple **google-services.json** files for different build
>   variants) by placing **google-services.json** files in dedicated
>   directories named for each variant under the app module root. For
>   example, if you have "**development**" and "**release**" build flavors, your
>   configuration could be organized like this:

```
app/
    google-services.json
    src/development/google-services.json
    src/release/google-services.json
    ...
```

You can find full instruction at [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your `google-services.json` are like this?

```
{
  "project_info": {
    ...
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        ...
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "nl.companyname"
        }
      },
      ...
    },
    {
      "client_info": {
        ...
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "nl.companyname.acc"
        }
      },
      ...
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

On your `app/gralde.build` try something like this

```
buildTypes {
    acceptance {
        applicationIdSuffix '.acc'
        ...
    }
    release {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove google-services.json from build.gradle

Create Application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setApplicationId("0")
                .build();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, options);
    }

}
```

Register this class in Manifest

```
 <application
        android:name=".extra.MyApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

On your Main Activity you need to call below method which generates FCM Token,(Which is similar like FirebaseInstanceIdService)

```
new GetFCMToken().execute();

 private class GetFCMToken extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //you can update this id based on your flavour
        String senderId = "1223";//put your FireBase project Sender Id


            String sToken = "";
            try {
                // Check for current token

                // Resets Instance ID and revokes all tokens.
                FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();

                // Clear current saved token
                // Check for success of empty token


                // Now manually call onTokenRefresh()
                Log.d("TAG", "Getting new token");
                sToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(senderId, "FCM");
                Log.d("TAG", "s" + sToken);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("e", "e", e);
            }
            return sToken;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String fcmToken) {
            super.onPostExecute(fcmToken);
            //Use this token to send notification
            Log.e("FCM_TOKEN",fcmToken);
           //Send Token server


        }

    }
```

You can find **SenderId** from firebase cosole -->Project Setting --> Cloud Messaging.
And Make sure you have added your package name in Fcm Console.

**FirebaseMessegingReceiver.class** work as it is.

Main benefit of this code is that,

1. No need to add google-services.json
2. Multiple firebase project work with single code.
3. No need to add FirebaseInstanceIdService in Manifest.